# SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

Hello Everyone I'm trying to retrive some data from my database but I'm getting

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'subject_id' in 'where clause'
```

It works if I retrive some other column of same table. I'm using spring and hibernate

Here is my controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAnyQuestion", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
String getAnyQuestion(
        @RequestParam(value = "subId", required = true) Long subId,
        @RequestParam(value = "questionType", required = true) String questionType) {

    Question questionList = questionService.getAnyQuestion(subId,questionType);

    if (questionList != null) {
        questionId = questionList.getId();
        return questionList.getQuestionText();
    }

    return "";
}
```

Here is my Service

```
 public Question getAnyQuestion(Long subId,String questionType) {             
    String query = "subject_id = " + subId +"  and "+ "questionType='" + questionType +"' and 1=1 order by rand()";       

    List<Question> questionList = hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(DetachedCriteria.forClass(Question.class).add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(query)),0,1);
    if (questionList.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return questionList.get(0);
}
```

and here is my domain

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name = "question")
public class Question {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@Column(length = 50)
private String questionType;
@Column(length = 5000)
private String questionText;

@ManyToOne
private Syllabus syllabus;
@ManyToOne
private Subject subject;
@ManyToOne
private Roll roll;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getQuestionText() {
    return questionText;
}

public void setQuestionText(String questionText) {
    this.questionText = questionText;
}

public String getQuestionType() {
    return questionType;
}

public void setQuestionType(String questionType) {
    this.questionType = questionType;
}

public Syllabus getSyllabus() {
    return syllabus;
}

public void setSyllabus(Syllabus syllabus) {
    this.syllabus = syllabus;
}


public Subject getSubject() {
    return subject;
}

public void setSubject(Subject subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}

public Roll getRoll() {
    return roll;
}

public void setRoll(Roll roll) {
    this.roll = roll;
}
```

}

Ful StackTrace is

```
    21296 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 1052, SQLState: 23000
21296 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Column 'subject_id' in where clause is ambiguous
Jun 26, 2013 7:30:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/Trainning] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Hibernate operation: could not execute query; SQL [select this_.id as id3_4_, this_.questionText as question2_3_4_, this_.questionType as question3_3_4_, this_.roll_id as roll4_3_4_, this_.subject_id as subject5_3_4_, this_.syllabus_id as syllabus6_3_4_, roll2_.id as id4_0_, roll2_.contact as contact4_0_, roll2_.rollno as rollno4_0_, roll2_.studentName as studentN4_4_0_, subject3_.id as id0_1_, subject3_.course as course0_1_, subject3_.sem as sem0_1_, subject3_.subjectName as subjectN4_0_1_, subject3_.syllabuspath as syllabus5_0_1_, syllabus4_.id as id6_2_, syllabus4_.chapterName as chapterN2_6_2_, syllabus4_.subject_id as subject3_6_2_, subject5_.id as id0_3_, subject5_.course as course0_3_, subject5_.sem as sem0_3_, subject5_.subjectName as subjectN4_0_3_, subject5_.syllabuspath as syllabus5_0_3_ from question this_ left outer join roll roll2_ on this_.roll_id=roll2_.id left outer join subject subject3_ on this_.subject_id=subject3_.id left outer join syllabus syllabus4_ on this_.syllabus_id=syllabus4_.id left outer join subject subject5_ on syllabus4_.subject_id=subject5_.id where subject_id = 1  and questionType='University' and 1=1 order by rand()]; Column 'subject_id' in where clause is ambiguous; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'subject_id' in where clause is ambiguous] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'subject_id' in where clause is ambiguous
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1041)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3566)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3498)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2568)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2275)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1812)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:697)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2232)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2129)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2124)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1597)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:306)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$35.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:966)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:366)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(HibernateTemplate.java:956)
    at org.Trainning.service.question.QuestionServiceImpl.getAnyQuestion(QuestionServiceImpl.java:91)
    at org.Trainning.controller.activities.ActivityController.getAnyQuestion(ActivityController.java:749)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:603)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:859)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:781)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

What I'm doing wrong please help me it works fine if i retrive syllabus data but give above error for subject

Here is the query generated by hibernate:

```
Hibernate: select this_.id as id3_4_, this_.questionText as question2_3_4_, this_.questionType as question3_3_4_, this_.roll_id as roll4_3_4_, this_.subject_id as subject5_3_4_, this_.syllabus_id as syllabus6_3_4_, roll2_.id as id4_0_, roll2_.contact as contact4_0_, roll2_.rollno as rollno4_0_, roll2_.studentName as studentN4_4_0_, subject3_.id as id0_1_, subject3_.course as course0_1_, subject3_.sem as sem0_1_, subject3_.subjectName as subjectN4_0_1_, subject3_.syllabuspath as syllabus5_0_1_, syllabus4_.id as id6_2_, syllabus4_.chapterName as chapterN2_6_2_, syllabus4_.subject_id as subject3_6_2_, subject5_.id as id0_3_, subject5_.course as course0_3_, subject5_.sem as sem0_3_, subject5_.subjectName as subjectN4_0_3_, subject5_.syllabuspath as syllabus5_0_3_ from question this_ left outer join roll roll2_ on this_.roll_id=roll2_.id left outer join subject subject3_ on this_.subject_id=subject3_.id left outer join syllabus syllabus4_ on this_.syllabus_id=syllabus4_.id left outer join subject subject5_ on syllabus4_.subject_id=subject5_.id where subject_id = 1  and questionType='University' and 1=1 order by rand() limit ?
```

As suggested by Yak here is my subject domain

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "subject")
public class Subject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(length=80)
    private Double course;
    @Column(length=60)
    private String subjectName;
    @Column(length=10)
    private Double sem;
    @Column(length=300)
    private String syllabuspath;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Double getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setCourse(Double course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

    public Double getSem() {
        return sem;
    }

    public void setSem(Double sem) {
        this.sem = sem;
    }

    public String getSubjectName() {
        return subjectName;
    }

    public void setSubjectName(String subjectName) {
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
    }

    public String getSyllabuspath() {
        return syllabuspath;
    }

    public void setSyllabuspath(String syllabuspath) {
        this.syllabuspath = syllabuspath;
    }


}
```

This is what desc gave me

```
| Field        | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | bigint(20)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| questionText | varchar(5000) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| questionType | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| roll_id      | bigint(20)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| subject_id   | bigint(20)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| syllabus_id  | bigint(20)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: All that and you didn't post the structure of your MySQL table... :) does the column even exist there, with that name, without spelling mistakes?

Comment: Please remove all your code, it is irrelevant. Instead, post the query as it is sent to MySQL. The DB is complaining about an SQL syntax error (`MySQLSyntaxErrorException`). A description of the tables involved in the query may be helpful too.

Comment: `Column 'subject_id' in where clause is ambiguous`
at the top of your error dump says pretty much all, it means that you have more than just one `subject_id` column in the tables you are selecting

Comment: @ N.B: Column exists in database

Comment: @luchosrock I have posted my question domain but it doesn't contain duplicate column

Comment: @PratikBhavsar - `Column 'subject_id' in where clause is ambiguous`. Your query, as I can see, contains **no aliases** and you're obviously joining another table which has a column with the same name. Solution is to send a properly formed query. Since we don't know what the actual query is..

Comment: @PratikBhavsar you're right, looking at the sql statement you can see that at least both `syllabus4_` and `this_` tables have a `subject_id` column

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disambiguate `column_id` in your `WHERE` clause:

```
where subject_id = 1  and questionType='University' and 1=1 order by rand() limit ?
```

I guess it is caused by this line of code:

```
String query = "subject_id = " + subId +"  and "+ "questionType='" + questionType +"' and 1=1 order by rand()";
```

It should be something like

```
String query = "this_.subject_id = " + subId +"  and "+ "this_.questionType='" + questionType +"' and 1=1 order by rand()";
```

Comment: @K.C - It didn't allowed me because i don't have enough reputation, but still i have to give it so i gave it in comment, n thanks for voting it up.:)

Answer (score 1):

Even I was facing this issue.
The cause for this happened due to a TRIGGER created on a table was scripted wrong.
I was referring to wrong column name/wrong table causing SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22

Answer (score 0):

If you are working spring boot(2 and above) yml then use this.

```
spring:
  jpa:
   hibernate:
     naming:
       physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have this error , try to change in your file where you write your table.

USE :

```
`import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
 import jakarta.persistence.Id;
 import jakarta.persistence.Table;`
```

INSTEAD OF :

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
```

Hope, this will help you with your application.